# v-slot:badge and v-if does not work with a computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm working on a CMS project and I have an issue I can't figure out.
I Have a component where I'm showing IP's. On change I want a badge to appear, so the user knows "this field is changed".

But the thing is the badge won't show if I'm using "v-slot:badge".
In the v-if is a computed property, If I inspect the page with vue devtools ‘isStartIpValueChanged’ will be true on a change. So, it should work right?

Template

```
<v-list-item-content>
<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid">
  <v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }">
    <v-row align-content="center" no-gutters>
      <v-col>
        <v-badge overlap color="red" right>
          <template v-slot:badge v-if="isStartIpValueChanged">
            <v-avatar color="red" size="6"></v-avatar>
          </template>
          <v-text-field
            dense
            :rules="apiIpRules"
            v-model="apiIp.startIp"
            @input="valueChanged()"
            ref="startIp"
            :class="hover ? 'hover-text-color' : ''"
            placeholder="###.###.###.###">
          </v-text-field>
        </v-badge>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="1" class="text-center" align-self="center">
        <p>-</p>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="1" class="text-center" align-self="center">
        <v-btn v-show="hover" @click="deleteIp()" icon small color="red"><v-icon>mdi-minus-circle</v-icon></v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-hover>
</v-form>
```

Created and Computed (apiIp is a prop I get from the parent component)

```
    created () {
    this.apiIpsOriginalValueStartIp = this.apiIp.startIp
    this.apiIpsOriginalValueEndIp = this.apiIp.endIp
    this.apiIp.uuid = this.GenerateUUID()
  },

    computed: {
    isStartIpValueChanged () {
      return this.apiIp &&
        (this.apiIp.startIp !== this.apiIpsOriginalValueStartIp ||
        this.apiIp.uuid === null)
    },
    isEndIpValueChanged () {
      return this.apiIp &&
        (this.apiIp.endIp !== this.apiIpsOriginalValueEndIp ||
        this.apiIp.uuid === null)
    }
  },
```

Anyone know what is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried using `v-show` instead of `v-if`?

Comment: Yes I tried, when using v-show the badge will always show, even when the computed property is false.

Answer (score 3):

As according to Vuetify's own documentation, you should be using the `v-model`, directly on the `v-badge`, to show it only when you want it to.

```
<v-badge overlap color="red" right v-model="isStartIpValueChanged">
  <template v-slot:badge>
    <v-avatar color="red" size="6"></v-avatar>
  </template>
  <v-text-field
    dense
    :rules="apiIpRules"
    v-model="apiIp.startIp"
    @input="valueChanged()"
    ref="startIp"
    :class="hover ? 'hover-text-color' : ''"
    placeholder="###.###.###.###">
  </v-text-field>
</v-badge>
```

Doc: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/badges#show-on-hover

Comment: When I inspected the html the badge + avatar where there but 0px x 0px. Today out of the blue they showed. mabey it had something to do with cache. It's still strange but it works so I'm happy

Comment: Great you got it working. It can happen that cache has some influence on Vue. Remember to mark the answer as correct if it helped you out.